# kCTUnderlineStyleSingle is not working for some character

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode6, nsattributedstring, nsmutableattributedstring

I am using `NSAttributedstring` with the attribute `kCTUnderlineStyleSingle`.
Character is underlining properly. But some character like *g, q, p* are not visible properly.

Even user cannot differentiate between g and q.

Is there any solution for that?

[image]

Comment: this may happen to some specified fonts. You maybe use another font.

Comment: @HoangVanHa I am using Gotham-Medium font. I need to use that only.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix it using this method:

```
- (void)addUnderlineWithRange:(NSRange)range
{
    int lineThickness = [EnvUtils isIpadEnv] ? 2 : 1;
    UIColor *lineColor = self.textColor;
    NSString *string = self.text;

    CGRect labelFrame = self.frame;
    CGSize expectedLabelSize = [NSString getMultilineTextSize:[string substringWithRange:range] forMaxSize:labelFrame.size font:self.font];
    CGSize expectedLabelFullSize = [NSString getMultilineTextSize:string forMaxSize:labelFrame.size font:self.font];

    CGSize xOffset = [NSString getMultilineTextSize:[string substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, range.location)] forMaxSize:labelFrame.size font:self.font];

    CGFloat originX = (labelFrame.size.width - expectedLabelFullSize.width) / 2 + xOffset.width;
    CGFloat originY = expectedLabelSize.height + (labelFrame.size.height - expectedLabelFullSize.height) / 2;
    CGRect lineFrame = CGRectMake(originX, originY, expectedLabelSize.width, lineThickness);

    UIView *lineView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:lineFrame] autorelease];
    lineView.backgroundColor = lineColor;

    [self.superview addSubview:lineView];
}
```